# Forward Propagate v.s. Forward Pass

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I saw some papers said forward pass and other papers say forward propagate.

Are those two words mean the same thing?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they typically mean the same thing, with some minor linguistic caveats.

Specifically, in typical backpropagation based neural network training there are two main steps, the forward pass, and the backward pass. During the forward pass, the variables are forward propagated through the network, while in the backward pass, the error is backward propagated through the network.

Answer (score -1):

Neural networks are trained with gradient based methods. To do that, you need calculute the partial derivative of the loss function with respect to each parameter. For this, you need to first calculate the loss function's value given current values of the parameters and then by using the inductive nature of the chain rule, you calculate the derivatives, this time starting from the loss layer. Both terms are used for the same value calculation operation, so they have the same meaning in the context of neural networks. Forward pass is also used for Hidden Markov Models sometimes for their inference algorithm. But it is hard to mix them, it should be understood from the context which algorithm has been meant.